# hibernate mapping - getting an error while running the hibernate configuration

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, annotations, hbm2ddl

I am trying to run Hibernate configuration from eclipse and create DB structure out of it. On running configuration I am getting the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier errors.
```

I used annotations to create hbm/pojo.
Below is the code. Im not sure if im missing something. Any help?

Configuration:
Eclipse Kepler SR2
Hibernate Core 4+
Oracle 10g
JDK 8 for Eclipse

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class RuleQuestion {

    //ATTRIBUTES
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    //QUestion NAME On JSP

    private String jspQuestion;

    //LEVEL of Question in RULE DATA MODEL
    private int level;
    //IF QUESTION has CHILD questions associated with it
    private boolean hasChildren;
    //IS MULTISELECT
    private boolean isMultiselect;
    //POSSIBLE ANSWERS FOR QUESTION
    /*@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "question")
    private List<RuleAnswer> possibleAnswers =new ArrayList<RuleAnswer>(0);
    *///ANSWER for Question
    private String answer;
    //DEFEAULT ANSWER
    private String defaultAnswer;
    /*//ASSOCIATED CHILDREN QUESTIONS
    private List<RuleQuestion> associatedQuestions;*/

    //Visibility
    private String visibility;

    public RuleQuestion()
    {

    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getJspQuestion() {
        return jspQuestion;
    }

    public void setJspQuestion(String jspQuestion) {
        this.jspQuestion = jspQuestion;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public boolean isHasChildren() {
        return hasChildren;
    }

    public void setHasChildren(boolean hasChildren) {
        this.hasChildren = hasChildren;
    }

    public boolean isMultiselect() {
        return isMultiselect;
    }

    public void setMultiselect(boolean isMultiselect) {
        this.isMultiselect = isMultiselect;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getDefaultAnswer() {
        return defaultAnswer;
    }

    public void setDefaultAnswer(String defaultAnswer) {
        this.defaultAnswer = defaultAnswer;
    }

    public String getVisibility() {
        return visibility;
    }

    public void setVisibility(String visibility) {
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }
```

}

Comment: You probablity miss `hbm2ddl.auto=update` hibernate property in your hibernate configuration

Comment: @orid I dint have this property set in hbm configuration. I update it with <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>. Not working.

Comment: Hi All I resolved it. 1) I changed column names with keyword values. (e.g. level) 2) For all classes in schema I marked them Serializable. (implements Serializable)

Answer (score 0):

Add below line after @Entity.

```
@Table(name="RuleQuestion")
```

The @Table annotation allows you to specify the details of the table that will be used to persist the entity in the database.

The @Table annotation provides four attributes, allowing you to override the name of the table, its catalogue, and its schema, and enforce unique constraints on columns in the table. For now we are using just table name which is EMPLOYEE.

Also add the

```
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer  id;
```

I have class that generate the Table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSACTION")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer  id;

    @Column(name="OCPP_START_TAG_ID",nullable=false)
    private String ocppStartTagId;

}
```

Comment: Hey Mahesh I tried it before but its not helping same errors.

Comment: @Column(name = "ID") in the above private Long Id also